# How to order docker container starting?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Hi I’m using sotify plugin for images and docker compose for building containers, but i want to wait for mysql to start and then my servise to start. Some kind of prioritized start of the containers. I’m using depends_on also. How can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can control the order of startup in docker compose, but what it means for a container to be "ready" will vary greatly across applications and thus there is no native way for one container to wait for another to be ready.

There are some suggested work arounds:

https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/